# Spring MVC: issue with conversionservice and @transactional on mvc controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, type-conversion, transactional

I get a `LazyInitializationException` by combining the `conversionservice` with a `@Transactional` behavior in a MVC controller.

Following fails:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@Transactional
public JsonUser getUser(@PathVariable("userId") User user) {
    // convertToJsonUser triggers lazy loading of User.adresses
    return mUserPresenter.convertToJsonUser(user);
}
```

... with following exception:
    org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: User.adresses, could not initialize proxy - no Session

But the same code without the conversionservice succeeds:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@Transactional
public JsonUser getUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId) {
    User user = mUserRepository.findOne(userId);
    // convertToJsonUser triggers lazy loading of User.adresses
    return mUserPresenter.convertToJsonUser(user);
}
```

and the same code without the transactional behavior succeeds:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public JsonUser getUser(@PathVariable("userId") User user) {
    // changedConvertToJsonUser DOESN'T trigger lazy loading of User.adresses
    return mUserPresenter.changedConvertToJsonUser(user);
}
```

**The conversion seems to occur in its own transaction before the main transaction to be opened by the `@Transactional` annotation.** As a result, the `User` loaded by the conversionmanager is not bound to the main transaction and lazy loading fails for that reason.

- Is that behavior known?
- How can I get rid of it?
- Did I forget something in the configuration?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: The transaction is started as soon as the method is called, the method is called after the conversion has taken place. Conversion etc. happen before the transaction. Next to that your view/web layer is definitely not the place to manage your transactional boundary. You can solve your problem by adding a `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` or interceptor.

Comment: Actually, it is very interesting: if it is not recommanded to open a transaction in the controller-layer, then why did Spring developers have developed the `conversionservice` feature? I mean, the conversionservice is per se the way of loading entities within a transaction from the very beginning of a call to the server, even before entering the controller. Personally, I thought it was a good idea to load entities as soon as possible - before reaching the service layer, because it ensures being "type-safe" and prevents ID conversion mismatch.

Comment: Starting a transaction and loading are different things. As mentioned in my initial comment you can use an `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` to overcome this (for lazy loading only an active `EntityManager` is needed not a transaction). Also I believe it isn't a good approach to use your entities in your view layer, it works in a small application but as soon as your application grows you will run into all sorts of trouble. But that is more of an architecture discussion, something for another question :).

Comment: @Deinum: Thank you! A last question: the controller should perform conversion between entities and representation, or not? By reading your answer, it seems that the conversion should occur within the transactional service performing the business logic, in order to free the controller from any entity. I get confused, as I thought that it was an underlying aspect of MVC pattern.

Comment: How you do it depends on your project, if you have a small project you still might want to expose your entities else do some conversion. This conversion can be either in the controller (create some view specific and optimized objects) and let the controller convert those to entities (or call a service method with some data which does the change/update). There is no general rule of thumb (there is no 1 architecture to rule them all, it depends on your (non) functional requirements and constraints from your environment).

Answer (score 0):

Controller is not a perfect place to put @Transactional annotations. It would be better to add them to service methods. This may cause problems because you may have a proxy object of controller which is mixed up with proxy from transaction manager and you can not predict what the order of execution will be. So my advice is: try to add a service layer.. even a very simple put there @Transactional annotations and test the code again.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and the justification. I was just thinking... actually I made a mistake: the issue is not related to the "@Transactional" behavior of the controller but rather simply to combination of `conversionservice` and `lazy loading`, both seems to be incompatible. I will analyze this deeper...

Answer (score 0):

> ... the conversionservice is per se the way of loading entities ...

No, it's not. It's like the name says: **conversion**. If you load entities, then that's your choice, not Spring's.

> if it is not recommanded to open a transaction in the controller-layer, then why did Spring developers have developed the conversionservice feature?

The **service** in ConversionService implies that we are **not** in the controller layer.

> The conversion seems to occur in its own transaction before the main transaction to be opened by the @Transactional annotation

There is no transaction opened by `@Transactional` in this case, because it doesn't work.

Transactions usually work on the service layer. You could have something like:

```
MyUserService implements UserService  {
  @Override
  @Transactional(readonly = true)
  public User getUserById(int id) {
```

But that's not your problem. Your problem is that the `User` object is not fully initialized. You would need a transaction on `convertToJsonUser`.

As a side note: The people who develop Spring prefer using the ids directly and load entities in the controller, not before.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! To summary: 1) `conversionservice` must be used only for simple conversions, that do not require any access to repositories. 2) `@Transactional` should not be used in controller layer (class nor operation level), among other because of technical issues due to conflicting dynamic proxies behaviors (see response @Marek Raszewski).

Comment: @jrg You can access repositories if you want, but be sure to understand the implications. I did it in the past without any problems. I don't do it anymore. Among other things I didn't like the fact that someone not familiar with your code doesn't know where the object is coming from. Whereas when you call `getUserById()` you know at once where to look in case of a problem.